# AWS Load Balancing Same Server Different Port

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I am just curios and probably the answer in no. But I was wondering if it is possible have a load balancing that listen on 1 server instead 2 or more and redirect the traffic on different ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no.  You can create different load balancer destination ports that point to the same instance port (80 -> 80, 1025 -> 80), but you cannot have the same load balancer port point to different instance ports (80 -> 80, 80 -> 81).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is now possible with Application Load Balancers by adding the same instance multiple times using different ports.

Here you can see the section where it allows to add an instance and specify the port:

[image]